# Как можно осуществить вывод товаров по критерию?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как можно вывести товары в WooCommerce, в имени которых есть например буква "б". Можно ли это сделать без плагинов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Штатными функциями WordPress или WooCommerce такой запрос не сделать. Остаётся только прямой запрос в базу, примерно так:

```
global $wpdb;

$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%б%' AND post_type = 'product'" );
```

Comment: Не годится, где prepare? :D

Comment: @Krya способ и так плохой, там и без prepare проблем хватает